# How to return custom object from resolver in graphql?

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-compose-mongoose, graphql-compose

I have nodejs and graphql application.

My User Schema and resolver using `graphql-compose-mongoose`:

```
import { composeWithMongoose } from 'graphql-compose-mongoose';

const UserTC = composeWithMongoose(User, {
  fields: { remove: ['password'] },
});

UserTC.addResolver({
  name: 'currentUser',
  type: UserTC.getType(),
  resolve: currentUserResolver, // return user object...
});
```

I add resolver to my UserTC:

```
UserTC.addResolver({
  name: 'login',
  args: {
    email: { type: 'String!' },
    password: { type: 'String!' },
  },
  type: /// <---- MISSING TYPE HERE
  resolve: async ({ args, context }) => {
    const { email, password } = args;
    const { token, user } = login({ email, password });
    return { token, user }
  },
});
```

I need to return { token, user } for this resolver.

What type should I defined?

This I try but failed:

```
type: { token: 'String', user: UserTC.getType() }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already solved the question, but this way you can define what you will use as **Args** and what fields can be **Exposed in the resolver**

```
const { schemaComposer, toInputObjectType } = require('graphql-compose');

const MyCustomAuth = schemaComposer.createObjectTC({
    name: 'Login',
    fields: {
        // Args
        username: 'String!',
        password: 'String!',
        // Fields to return
        email: 'String',
        city: 'String',
        token: 'String'
    }
});

const MyCustomAuthITC = toInputObjectType(MyCustomAuth);
```

Here's an example using **JWT**

```
UserTC.addResolver({
    kind: 'mutation',
    name: 'Auth',
    // Your Custom Object
    type: MyCustomAuth,
    args: {
        // Here goes the Input    
        input: MyCustomAuthITC
    },
    resolve: async ({args}) => {
        return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
            const { username, password } = args.input;
            //Get user by username
            const user = await User.findOne({username});
            if (!user) reject('Authentication Failed');
            const token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), config.JWT_SECRET, {
                expiresIn: '1h',
                subject: user.id
            });            
            resolve({
                email: user.email,
                city: user.email,
                token: token
            });
        });
    }    
});
```

Now you need to call the resolver somewhere like this `login: UserTC.getResolver('Auth')`

Comment: i think you can use addArgs function but despite you use addResovler you need use mongooseresolver to make your code more clean